# Game Center share achievement or leaderboard crashes on iPad iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, game-center

Hello everyone I am trying to implement Game Center on my iOS8 app and have run into a crash on the iPad. I already have the achievements and leaderboards set up and can successfully hit the blue share button on the iPhone but when i press share on the iPad the GKGameCenterViewController crashes and gives me the following report:

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController
>   (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController:
>   0x7b1480a0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set
>   before the presentation occurs.' terminating with uncaught exception
>   of type NSException abort() called CoreSimulator 110.4 - Device: iPad
>   Retina - Runtime: iOS 8.1 (12B411) - DeviceType: iPad Retina

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same crash. When I present the GKGameCenterViewController modally, it's important I provide the sourceView, using the code in this order:

```
    gameCenterVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    gameCenterVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view!
    gameCenterVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view!.frame
    presentViewController(gameCenterVC, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Your error reads

> "reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController [...]"

which suggests your modalPresentationStyle = .Popover.

In that case, you will need to set the source view or button bar, like the rest of the error indicates.

The instance popoverPresentationController in non-nil because...

> If you created the view controller but have not yet presented it, accessing this property creates a popover presentation controller when the value in the modalPresentationStyle property is UIModalPresentationPopover

according to [popoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621428-popoverpresentationcontroller?language=objc)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing on an iPad Air with iOS 9.3.

I am getting it to run without crashing [using my solution in the above post], but it does not display the game center popups or view controllers with

```
modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
```

However, I do get my view controllers and sign in pop ups when I set

```
modalPresentationStyle = .Fullscreen
```